# UnicodeEncodeError when writing to file

Tags: python, linux, character-encoding, locale

I have a python script that works great on my local machine (OS X), but when I copied it to a server (Debian), it does not work as expected. The script reads an xml file and prints the contents in a new format. On my local machine, I can run the script with stdout to the terminal or to a file (i.e. `> myFile.txt`), and both work fine.

However, on the server (`ssh`), when I print to terminal everything works fine, but printing to the file (which is what I really need) gives UnicodeEncodeError: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)`. All files are in utf-8 encoding, and utf-8 is declared in the magic comment.

If I print the `str` objects inside a list (which is a trick I usually use to get a handle on encoding issues), it also throws the same error.

If I use `print( x.encode('utf-8') )`, then it prints code-style bits (e.g. `b'1'    b'\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0'`).

If I `$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in the shell (as suggested in some SO posts), then I get a binary file: `1       <D0><9A><D0><B0><D0><BC><D0><B0>`.

I have checked all of the `locale` variables and the relevant ones match what I have on my local machine.

I can simply process the file locally and upload it, but I really want to understand what is happening here. Since the python code is working on one computer, I am not sure that it is relevant, but I am adding it below:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

corpus = ET.parse('file.xml')
text = corpus.getroot()
for body in text :
  for sent in body :
    depDOMs = [(0,'') for i in range(len(sent)+1)]
    for word in sent :
      if word.tag == 'LF' :
        pass
      elif 'ID' in word.attrib and 'FEAT' in word.attrib and 'DOM' in word.attrib :
        ID = word.attrib['ID']
        try :
          Form =  word.text.replace(' ','_')
        except AttributeError :
          Form = '_'
        try :
          Lemma =  word.attrib['LEMMA'].replace(' ', '_')
        except KeyError :
          Lemma = '*NULL*'
        CPOS = word.attrib['FEAT'].split()[0]
        POS = word.attrib['FEAT'].replace( ' ' , '_' )
        Feats = '_'
        Head = word.attrib['DOM']
        if Head == '_root' :
          Head = '0'
        try :
          DepRel = word.attrib['LINK']
        except KeyError :
          DepRel = 'ROOT'
        PHead = '_'
        PDepRel = '_'
        try:
          if word.attrib['NODETYPE'] == 'FANTOM' :
            word.attrib['LEMMA'] = '*'+word.attrib['LEMMA']+'*'
        except KeyError :
          pass
        print( ID , Form , Lemma , Feats, CPOS , POS , Head , DepRel , PHead , PDepRel , sep='\t' )
      else :
        print( 'WARNING: what is this?',sent.attrib['ID'],word.attrib)
  print()
```

Comment: Please supply the code you're using

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Code is added. Regarding your question edits, how do you know that this is purely a python problem, and not bash/io? Why is it that python's output is dependent on the destination of the output?

Comment: Cool. It's because the error happens when you write to a file, therefore Bash is not involved (unless you mean redirecting). The I/O tag is more about physical I/O

Comment: I presume you're running as Python 3 on both boxes?

Comment: Can you show how you're "printing to a file"?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Yes, running python3 on both boxes. I have tried both `python3 script.py > output.txt` and `with myFile as open('x', 'w'): ... print( *variableList, file=myFile)`. Same result.

Comment: It seems that ElementTree is not decoding to Unicode as it should be as you're getting UTF-8 encoded bytes strings. Can you add `print( type (Form))` above your existing `print` and run on both nodes?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack The objects are `str` in both locations. I should have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91311/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-bebop).

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack `sudo locale-gen` fixed it! If you want to write up an answer, you deserve far more than the usual points. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great news! It's a new one for me. I'm glad we worked it out. See my answer below. Good luck!

Comment: Generally speaking when writing to a file is a different case, since the console may have UTF-8 encoding, but that's not necessary the case for `sys.stdout.encoding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue may be caused by a miss configuration of Linux's locales, meaning that Python is being too cautious when printing non-ASCII chars.

Confirm locale configuration with `locale`. If there's a problem, you'll see something like:

```
$ locale 
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE=
```

Fix this with:

```
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
```

(replace "en_US.UTF-8" with the locale that's not working). For further info, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue

Answer (score -1):

You can find important information related to the error you are experiencing in the attributes of the UnicodeError based exception.

Quoting the documentation:

> **UnicodeError** has attributes that describe the encoding or decoding
> error. For example, `err.object[err.start:err.end]` gives the particular
> invalid input that the codec failed on.
>
> **encoding**
>
> The name of the encoding that raised the error.
>
> **reason**
>
> A string describing the specific codec error.
>
> **object**
>
> The object the codec was attempting to encode or decode.
>
> **start**
>
> The first index of invalid data in object.
>
> **end**
>
> The index after the last invalid data in object.