# How to print overline character in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, locale

Please don't mark my question as already answered, because in all of the questions on stackoverflow or in the Unicode HOWTO I can't figure out how to print the overline or U+203E character in Python 3. Can someone please explain in baby programmer language how to print unicode characters like this one? I have tried some things, but to be honest I had no idea what I was doing.

I am working Kubuntu xenial (16.04).

When I try to print the character I get a UnicodeEncodeError. My question would be, how to work around this error?

**EDIT 1: Problem located**

I have now figured out my locale is set to POSIX, which would be ASCII encoding. I will try to set it to UTF-8 encoding.

**EDIT 2: Still no solution**

I have found out what I need to change, I just haven't found out how to. For anyone with the same issue, there's a comment with a link to a post where a similar problem is solved.

**EDIT 3: Final answer**

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978559/can-and-should-i-become-owner-of-etc-default-locale) is a link to an askubuntu forum where I asked how to edit my `/etc/default/locale` file. Turns out one command in the Linux shell was enough. For me a lot of stuff doesn't work, but this command allowed me to set my locale to en_US.UTF-8: `sudo /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. After rebooting my OS, the settings had applied and my locale was changed.

Now I don't need the overline character anymore, because I have learned to work with graphics libraries, but I have had multiple problems because of my locale. Thanks to everyone for the advice!

Comment: `print("\u203e")`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that gives me a UnicodeEncodeError. I will edit my question for clarification

Comment: Yeah, that means your terminal doesn't support unicode, or doesn't have unicode support enabled (i.e. it's set to decoding things using some other codec)

Comment: What error are you getting *exactly*? But yes, the problem is likely with your terminal, not with Python.

Comment: This is the exact error I get: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u203e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Yes, either your terminal doesn't accept unicode characters, or Python is under the impression that it doesn't. Try changing your terminal setttings.

Comment: Try something like the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408791/python-3-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: @HylkevanderVeen, have you solved the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408791/python-3-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters

Answer (score 2):

Use `\u` to indicate a unicode character: `print("\u203e")`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the combining character U+0304 instead.

```
print(u'a\u0304')
```

ā
U+0305 is probably a better choice (as viraptor suggests). You can also use the Unicode Roman numerals (U+2160 through U+217f) instead of regular uppercase Latin letters, although (at least in my terminal) they don't render as well with the overline.

```
 print(u'\u2163\u0305')
```

Ⅳ̅

```
 print u'I\u0305V\u0305'
```

I̅V̅

Comment: I just want the plain overline character, without any characters underneath it, so I need \u203e. My problem is I don't know how to fix the UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: I really don't have any code. This is all I have: 'print (u"\u203e")'

Comment: humm, try with python -c 'print (u"\u203e")'  and python3 -c 'print (u"\u203e")', the same answers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `sys.stdout.encoding` is `'ascii'`.
Try to set it to `'utf-8'`:

```
import sys, codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.detach())

print ('\u203e')
```

Comment: If I try that, this is my result: ���

Answer (score -2):

```
print(u' \u0305'*k)
```

with `k` as the length of the line in characters.

e.g.

```
print(u' \u0305'*5)
```

Comment: This completely misses the point of the question, and also it was adequately answered years ago.